# partially visible spine matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am interested in creating a plot where only part of the spine is visible (say only for positive values), while the plot is shown for both negative and positive values.

```
set_position  # seems to only set the point where it intersects with the other axis

set_visible   # is an on-off switch. It does not allow for partial visibility.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ax` as the axes, if the x-axis is to show only between 0 and 0.5, then:

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_bounds((0, 0.5))
```

You might need to set the ticks, as well, so, for instance:

```
ax.set_xticks([0, 0.25, 0.5])
```